# Adding a key to a dictionary where the values are lists In Python

Tags: python

I want to add the variable key to the dictionary as a key, as well as add a value to a list. Is this the right way of going about this?

```
dict = {}
key = 'hold'
value = 'holdtwo'
value_two = 'holdthree'
dict[key].append(value)
dict[key].append(value_two)
```

Comment: Use `defaultdict(list)`? Or just set `dict[key] = []` first? Note I wouldn't recommend shadowing the built-in `dict`.

Comment: @Patrick - I assume that the last sentence of query could be rephrased as "Is this the best way of going about this?"

Comment: @amiga  By what objective criteria? What is best?  The code as postes is clearly providign a stacktrace with an error message that would lead to the solution of adding a list first before appending to it. Its not magic it is normal debugging. Folllowing up on the error message and trying to solve it with existing posts on SO comes before asking.

Comment: @Patrick. Well, a better way of doing it would not be calling the variable a keyword. Or  separately declaring a key or two variables when all could be done in one line. Or the appending could be done in one line rather than 2. Loads of room for improvement by **any** objective measure.

Comment: The thing is, I don't know what the keys are until I read in a file. File input gives me the keys I want based on some string searching while parsing each line, then I want to make that line a key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dedfaultdict to achieve this

```
from collections import defaultdict

dictionary = defaultdict(list)
key = 'hold'
value = 'holdtwo'
value_two = 'holdthree'
dictionary[key].append(value)
dictionary[key].append(value_two)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use use keywords as variables!

```
dict = {} # dict is a keyword
```

Your asking for problems with it!

```
dict1 = {}
dict1['key'] = ['hold','hold2','hold3']
dict1['key'].append('hold4')
```

or a more extensive and larger variation on holding stuff (example):

```
dict1 = {}
keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

for key1 in keys:
    dict1[key1] = []

vals = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]  #Just some values to store in the dicts

iKey = 1  #iKey is just an offset to show the differences between keys
for key2 in dict1:
    iKey = iKey + 5
    for val in vals:
        dict[key2].append(iKey*val)
```

Loads of options.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

If I want to put in a new key that has an empty list, I use:

```
new_key = 'something'
dict[new_key] = []
```

If I want to add a value to an existing key's list:

```
value = 'something else'
dict[new_key].append(value)
```

This seems to work just fine with variables as keys.